# Selenium PhantomJs Python Unable to Find Element

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to use the headless browser. However, I keep getting an error when I try to .sendkeys to an xpath selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time



driver=webdriver.PhantomJS("C:\\Users\\ikhan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\selenium\\webdriver\\phantomjs.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="lst-ib"]''').send_keys("anish")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="lst-ib"]''').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ikhan/Desktop/SoftsystemSolutions/SupremeBot/headless.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="lst-ib"]''').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  File "C:\Users\ikhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 313, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\ikhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 791, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\ikhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ikhan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"103","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:64743","User-Agent":"Python http auth"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"xpath\", \"value\": \"//*[@id=\\\"lst-ib\\\"]\", \"sessionId\": \"c7193fb0-8381-11e7-80d0-b324a0b7e579\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/c7193fb0-8381-11e7-80d0-b324a0b7e579/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

I have tried to use this code using chrome browser and it works just fine. I have also tried using an id selector.

Comment: I've had the same problem. I used `time.sleep` instead of `driver.implicitly_wait` and it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this for a different site and it works fine. I think it just timed out

Comment: Why are you using XPath to find a simple ID? Use `.find_element_by_id()`. The error message states the element can't be found. It could be for many reasons... the locator is wrong, the element isn't available yet, etc. What have you tried to locate it?

Answer (score 0):

To locate the Google Search Box use the `name` locator as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe")
driver.get("https://google.com")
google_search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
google_search.send_keys("anish")
google_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print("Google Search Complete")
```